# Managed array issue in C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, clr, managed, managed-c++

compilng with /clr

```
array<Byte>^ byteArray =  gcnew array<Byte>(25);
```

Why would I get these compiler errors?

```
error C2065: 'array' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'gcnew' : undeclared identifier
error C2275: 'System::Byte' : illegal use of this type as an expression
error C3192: syntax error : '^' is not a prefix operator (did you mean '*'?)
```

I am calling this method inside a class with

```
using namespace System;

__gc class MyClass
```

This feels like I am missing something very basic here. Even this causes errors:

```
array<Byte>^ byteArray;
```

or

```
array<Byte> * byteArray;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Make sure the project that you've created is a C++/CLI project.

Comment: Maybe, one of your headers contains `#pragma unmanaged` somewhere

Comment: If that class declaration compiles then you are using /clr:oldsyntax.  Or a really old version of VS, before VS2005.  Neither of which will parse *array<>*

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `__gc class` was used in the, now obsolete, Managed C++. In C++/CLI, use `ref class`.

For more information see [the section *Syntax changes* in the Wikipedia article *C++/CLI*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Syntax_changes).

Comment: Don't forget that C++/CLI itself also has a newer, somewhat incompatible revision, called C++/CX.

Comment: @Arafangion That's not a revision of C++/CLI, that's something different: it's not related to .Net in any way. But it uses the same (or very similar) syntax as C++/CLI.